# String returned by pyodbc different than a normal string?

Tags: python, pyodbc, richtext

I used pyodbc to get some data from an mssql db. The returned text contains \n whenever a newline is necessary. I loaded all the text into the "row" variable.

```
var=row.somecolumnfromdatabase
var2=str('Some text\nand the newline.')

print(RichText(var))
print(RichText(var2))
```

However, if I use a function like RichText (from docxtpl) to transform the string, I receive different results. In the case of "var" (text loaded from db), the \n symbol is preserved. In the case of var2 (where I input the text by hand), the \n is transformed correctly. Simply printing var and var2 without transformations shows no difference and I would expect the contained strings to be identical - e.g. the RichText function should receive the exact same input.

What am I missing?

Comment: Look at the [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) of each string.  `print(repr(var))` and `print(repr(var2))`.  You will probably see some difference.

Comment: Indeed, the string returned by pyodbc has escaped the newlines (as \\n). Any way I can tell it to not do this?

Comment: Without needing to use .replace("\\n", "\n"), of course

Comment: My guess is that you need to look further up the chain to figure out why your database contains strings that have newline characters replaced by the the string representation of newlines.  How did the data get that way to begin with?  I don't think this will end up being `pyodbc`'s fault.  You may need to rework your question once you've looked into this further.